# Does returning this on every method matters on performance sensitive programs

Tags: c++

Lets say I have the following code:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test& method1()
    {
        // do stuff...
        return *this;   
    }
    Test& method2()
    {
        // do some other stuff...
        return *this;   
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.method1().method2();
}
```

The only reason we would return `this` (on my opinion) is to make it practicle to use and chain methods.

I do believe however that there is a performance cost that is usually negligeable.

However, if I find myself in a setting where performance matters, should I avoid these or will it be optimized away? Where could I find actual data on the performance cost of it so I can judge by myself if it is negligeable for my case or not?

Comment: Try it on godbolt.org, like this : https://godbolt.org/z/e5ccnb9ex (at the moment everything is optimized away since your methods don't do anything)

Comment: There's no guarantee that such thing gets optimized. In particular if recursion is involved, it is likely it won't get optimized. Besides. if this is a performance sensitive code, then you should not depend on optional compiler optimizations. That being said, the cost of returning this is neglible.

Comment: Also: "Where could I find actual data on the performance cost" - by measuring by yourself. Just run a benchmark.

Comment: Write the code as you normally would.  After you get a working program, then profile it and find the parts that are slowing you down.  That's really the best way (IMHO) to optimize code.

Comment: Let's say that this pattern is not optimized entirely away and we're on x64 linux, then the direct impact is `mov rax, rdi` or *at worst* storing `rdi` to the stack and loading it back out before returning. The indirect impact (knock-on effects such as the compiler performing different optimizations or forgoing them), who knows. The actual *cost* of that direct impact would be context-dependent anyway so there's still no general answer.

Comment: read about the as-if rule. In a nutshell, when you do not use the value returned from a method, eg `test.method1();` then it makes no difference whether the reference is actually returned or not, hence the compiler is allowed to emit code that is not returning anything

Comment: compilers are much better at spotting opportunities for optimization than humans. That doesnt imply that you should trust blindly, but it does imply that you must measure what the compiler produces from different variants of your code when you care about performance. You can try here https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: A much bigger impact is whether or not you inline-define your member function (as in your post) or define them in their own compilation unit. For the former, the compiler can see the code and optimise it for every instance, but at the cost of having to recompile your function for every compilation unit. For the latter, the call will not be removed. Returning a pointer or not is then the least of your worries. [Example comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/vM65ob4fM)